# Prove line joining midpoints of non-parallel sides of trapezoid is parallel to the parallel sides of the trapezoid

Tags: geometry

If I have a trapezoid with two sides parallel, and a line going through the midpoints of the other two sides, how do I prove that this line is also parallel to the two parallel sides of the trapezoid?

[image: Trapezoid]

Assuming $AD || BC$ and $AE=EB$ and $DF=FC$, how do I prove that $EF||AD||BC$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without loss of generality, |AD|<|BC|. Draw a line passing through A and meeting BC at G and EF at H. Since AGCD is a parallelogram, H is the midpoint of AG. Note that triangles AEH and ABG are similar, hence, EH is parallel to BG, and the result follows.

Comment: yes, this helped me greatly. thank you !! ^_^

Answer (score 1):

Proof

Let  ABCD  be a trapezoid with the bases  AB  and  DC  and the mid-line  EF    Compare the triangles  DFC  and  FBG.

The segments  FC  and  BF  are congruent since the point  F  is the midpoint 
 of the side  BC.  The angles  DFC  and  BFG are congruent as the vertical angles. 
 The angles  DCF  and  FBG are congruent as the alternate exterior angles 
 at the parallel lines  AB  and  DC  and the transverse  BC.
 Hence, the triangles  DFC  and  FBG are congruent in accordance with the  ASA-test of congruency of triangles.
 It implies that the segments  DF  and  GF  are congruent as the corresponding sides of the congruent triangles  DFC  and  FBG.

Thus the mid-line  EF  of the trapezoid  ABCD  is the straight line segment connecting the midpoints of the triangle  AGD.

It is well known fact that the the straight line segment connecting the midpoints of the triangle  AGD  is parallel to the triangle base  AG  and its length is half of the length of the triangle base.  In our case,  the length of the segment  EF  is half of the length  AG :   |EF| = 1/2*|AG| = 1/2*(|AB| + |BG|). 
 Since  |BG| = |DC|  from the triangles congruency,  we have  |EF| = 1/2*(|AB| + |DC|),  or  |EF| = 1/2*(a + d),  where  a  and  d  are the lengths of the trapezoid bases.

**Summary**
 The mid-line of a trapezoid is parallel to its bases. 
 The length of the mid-line of a trapezoid is half of the sum of the lengths of its bases.